# Where is the TcpListener class for WinRT?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am trying to follow the example given on this page:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C

but I am developing for a Metro / WinRT Store app. When I try to use a lot of the classes that it says to use, there are a ton of them missing. I know this is because they decided to get rid of a lot of libraries when migrating... but does anyone know how I would be able to reference the missing classes? The TcpListener class is missing. Or does anyone know of a free library that I can reference in replacement of the missing libraries?

Answer (score 6):

You can't reference the missing classes. They don't exist unfortunately. There are many built-in replacements though for lots of the functionality, and at this point, there really isn't a large ecosystem around WinRT and 3rd party replacements for missing functionality.

That being said, for TCPListener, you may have good success by replacing it with the [StreamSocketListener](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR226906&ei=r4mIUPnxJoO-yQH_2oHwDQ&usg=AFQjCNGXi4caRPrNPKlzql0TXjLcKgtktw&sig2=vgY9ANBGkGwz0E69zrlIOw).  [Here's](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931) a full sample using StreamSocket and StreamSocketListener.